# How to create users with different fields?

Tags: django, django-models

Currently using the custom created user as its Django recommended way to handle users for projects.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want, please elaborate your question some more.

Comment: @guillermochamorro I would like one user to be a Client, and one user type to be a Employee. The Client will have fields such as address. The Employee will have field such as hours available to work, team. I would like new registered users to automatically be Clients on the main site register form. I would like Clients and Employees to have different views when they sign in.